# Angular (11) API Request Caching

Tags: angular, typescript, caching, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

Angular 11 is available and I would like to know which practice is currently the most common one to cache API responses of (GET) Requests. I've read multiple tutorials and documents, but I have still some questions.

1. I came accros a client-side caching approach which is using [localstorage](https://dev.to/maurogarcia_19/client-side-caching-with-angular-2i6l). It looks really clean and understandable, but is it a common apporach to save requests/responses in such a way?
2. RxJS seems to be an alternative, but most examples are using a global expiration time. I would like to have the option to set the expiration per requests. Is it even possible to implement such mechanism with RxJS?
3. Using [interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#using-interceptors-for-caching) seems the be an option as well, but, again, most examples don't show a way to set the expiration time.

In other words, this seems to be a to broad to answer question, but I would like to get an answer on the main subject: Which caching mechanism, which includes an expiration time per request response, suits the described needs?

(Please post a comment if more detailed information is required.)

Comment: I think this blog https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/caching-http-requests-with-angular/ demonstrates cache with expiration using interceptors (my preferred tool for the job).

Comment: @Benny Thank you for your comment. The example is using a global maxAge variable instead of a expiration per request. Is it possible to somehow, set an expiration per request while using a http interceptor?

Comment: I did not try it myself, but it appears to me that you can enhance the code in the blog and have expiration per request.

Comment: Have a look into this lib: https://github.com/ngneat/cashew never used it but the author does good stuffs usually :)

Comment: Have you thought about a regular HTTP caching for GET requests? localStorage and rxjs are good for storing `data`, not requests